# Ember.js Won't Accept Root URL

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, url-routing

I am trying to create an Ember.js app on a domain that has a ton of different sublevel sites. I'm trying to set my `rootURL` to '`/org/new/`' like the [docs say](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) so that the root URL will be `mydomain.com/org/new/`. I'm using the following router code:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/org/new/'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('carouselItems', { path: '/' }, function() {
    // child routes
  });
});

App.CarouselItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('carouselItem');
  }
});
```

However, my app keeps trying to load mydomain.com/carouselItems instead. I have a `CarouselItemsController` that extends `ArrayController` and a `CarouselItemController` that extends `ObjectController`. Both are used when the user navigates to mydomain.com/org/new/ to generate some items in a Bootstrap carousel.

Comment: When you load http://mydomain.com/org/new/#/ what would happen? Auto-redirect to http://mydomain.com/?

Comment: @Daniel No, mydomain.com is a university website, hosting sites for many student orgs. mydomain.com/org/new is the root domain, at which further paths, e.g. mydomain.com/org/new/photos, may be appended.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to understand what behaviour/error you get when you try to load the ember-app. I don't quite get what you mean by "my app keeps trying to load mydomain.com/carouselItems". So.. is it a blank page when you open "mydomain.com/org/new/"?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you fully get how an ember app is structured. If you have an ember app available on http://mydomain.com/org/new/, the URLs of different states of the app actually are: http://mydomain.com/org/new/#/photos, http://mydomain.com/org/new/#/history, etc. (note the # in URL)

Comment: @Daniel Urls are built according to the specified location-setting in Ember. Your example would be using HashLocation whilst sethfri seems to be using HistoryLocation. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html

Comment: I see.. thanks I wasn't aware of that. Didn't come across that in the guide and examples.

Comment: @sethfri have you found any solution?

Comment: @rain Unfortunately not. I ended up just abandoning my Ember app sometime ago.

Comment: @sethfri have posted a similar question on ember discussion http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/confusion-about-rooturl/6631?u=rainbow99984 hope to get some idea

Comment: By saying "my app keeps trying to load `mydomain.com/carouselItems`" are you referring to the AJAX query that goes out and fetch your `carouselItems`? If so, this has nothing to do with the `rootURL` defined on your router, it's the adapter's concern. Which makes sense, because if you want to use an external service, you don't want the rootURL get into the mix. Define an adapter class and use the `namespace` property: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_namespace